Self-Hosted GitHub Runner idling and not picking up Jobs
My Self-Hosted Windows GitHub Runner is not picking up job when it has been inactivate for about 1-2 hours.
So when first connecting it, it's picking up jobs but then when there is no jobs for a while the GitHub Workflow will show: Waiting for a Runner to pick up this Job while the UI for my Runner says its idle.GitHub UI
When i check the log on my Runner it says it's ready to pick up jobs. When i restart the runner cmd it's picking up jobs normally again.
Runner Log
I am expecting it to poll correctly without having to restart it every so often.

Make sure that your Windows machine does not go to sleep or hibernation mode. Also make sure that your network supports long running connections.
Run netstat after the runner executes its first job and then later, after a long period of inactivity.
